# Scan directory and rename files in Python

Tags: python

I have 7 files in my **web** directory like this :

[image]

I'm trying to scan through all my files in that folder and rename a certain files.

I have

```
import os

path = '/Users/username/Desktop/web'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.startswith("test"):
        print 'found'
        os.rename(filename, filename.replace("test_", " "))
    else:
        continue
```

After run it,

**python scan_dir.py**

I got

```
found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scan_dir.py", line 9, in <module>
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace("test_", " "))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any hints on what I did wrong ?

Comment: Is there any reason you're doing this in Python rather than with an existing tool like Rename Master?

Comment: Also note that your new filenames will begin with a space.

Comment: Additionally, a basic Google search for "python os.rename no such file or directory" (most of which was autocompleted by a Google suggestion) yielded several useful results including the linked duplicate. Please do a few seconds of research before posting a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `rename` you should use the full path:

```
import os

path = '/Users/name/Desktop/web'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.startswith("test"):
        print 'found'
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.replace("test_", " ")))
    else:
        continue
```

In your current code what you do use try to rename the file `test_3.jpg` (from your example) in the **current** directory, which probably don't exists.

BTW, I would concider using the [`glob` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) instead.

Comment: Any reason to go with string formatting rather than `os.path.join`?

Comment: No specific reason. In this specific case I don't think `os.path.join` is required, but can use both.

Comment: Changed to `os.path.join` :)

Comment: There are avails should be 'os.path.join': it is the right cross-platform way to do the job.